# swift переход между viewController в Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Как реализовать переход на новые между двумя ViewControlerами в xCode 11, чтобы не было  всплывающего экрана свертывания вверху второго контроллера [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Вот код открывания NewViewController из Вашего контроллера,
одна строчка в нем решает, каким будет вид открываемого нового контроллера (смахиваемый или на весь экран), я отметил её каментом:

```
if let newViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewViewController") as? NewViewController {
    newViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve // это значение можно менять для разных видов анимации появления
    newViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext // это та самая волшебная строка, убрав или закомментировав ее, вы получите появление смахиваемого контроллера
    present(newViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
   }
```

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос, а куда вставлять данное условие?

Comment: В то место, откуда вам нужен переход на новый контроллер. Например, в тело Экшена какой-нибудь кнопки. В этом условии метод present непосредственно показывает новый контроллер, а все остальное подготовка к этому.